# Traversing objects in python

Tags: python

How can I write this code without repeating myself indefinitely?

```
fields = row.split('__')

if len(fields) == 1:
    foo = getattr(bundle.obj, fields[0])
elif len(fields) == 2:
    foo = getattr(getattr(bundle.obj, fields[0]), fields[1])
elif len(fields) == 3:
    foo = getattr(getattr(getattr(bundle.obj,
                            fields[0]), fields[1]), fields[2])
# etc ..
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use [`reduce()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reduce):

```
foo = reduce(getattr, fields, bundle.obj)
```

or a simple loop:

```
foo = bundle.obj
for field in fields:
    foo = getattr(foo, field)
```

Comment: I feel like every day I learn about another built-in function that is incredibly useful.  That Guido is one smart benevolent dictator :)

Comment: @JasonSperske: Actually, Guido can't remember who convinced him to add `reduce` in the early days, but he's wanted to get rid of it ever since. And many of the other core devs agree with him. They hate it with a passion, and in the 3.0 transition, were just barely persuaded to move it to `functools` and just stop talking about it instead of removing it entirely. (Personally, I think there are some cases where `reduce` makes things more readable—rare, but this is definitely one of them.)

Comment: @abarnert: No doubt it was one of those obnoxious Lisp people. :D  (I'd say "one of *us*" except that I never wrote much Lisp, even when I was hanging out with the AI grad students....)  Hasn't there been a lot of grumbling about `map` as well?

Comment: @JasonSperske: I think a lot of it is a matter of taste and a knowledge of history.  Both `map` and `reduce` came out of various functional languages, and lots of bits of Python are [stolen I mean borrowed](http://nancyprager.wordpress.com/2007/05/08/good-poets-borrow-great-poets-steal/) from other languages as well.  Getting the right mix of ideas with workable syntax and so on, well, that's where "taste" comes in.  Python has it, perl ... not so much. :D

Comment: @torek: A lot less. Guido did originally suggest getting rid of `map` and `filter` when he added comprehensions, but since various people have started using `map` to contrast with `reduce` (as in "not all functional tools are as useless as `reduce`—look at `map`, which everyone loves as a builtin") he's come around to their way of thinking.

Comment: Also, they're not entirely wrong: `map` and `filter` translate better from conses to arrays and iterators than `fold`/`reduce` does. (Haskell only makes `fold` work with infinite lazy lists by giving you, in effect, O(1) ways of slicing off an infinite initial subset.)